# Посчитать li и вбить теги

Tags: php

собственно прошу подсказать такой момент
выводится список значений через

```
echo "<div>" . mb_strtoupper( $key, 'utf-8' ) . "</div><ul>";
foreach( $items as $value ) 
{
 $value = explode(",", $value);
 if ((string)preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value[1])) {
 echo "<li><a href=\"/krovlya26/$value[1]/\">" . $value[0] . '</a></li>';
}
} 
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

нужно вставить через каждый 5 выводящийся li свой тег, подскажите направление...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно красивее, но это быстрый способ)

```
echo "<div>" . mb_strtoupper($key, 'utf-8') . "</div><ul>";
$count = 0;
foreach ($items as $value) {
    if ($count === 4) {
        //you tag
        $count = 0;
    }
    $value = explode(",", $value);
    if ((string) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value[1])) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"/krovlya26/$value[1]/\">" . $value[0] . '</a></li>';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую... примерно так и предполагал, что через count.

Comment: да, все ок. спасибо, правда вылезла другая беда, но это в процессе.